# Refactor Java Program

Tags: java

Problem: I have list of houses in an Array. I need to make sure atleast one list consist of only houses with cat and atleast one list consist of only houses with dog. A list should only contain one kind of houses (i.e no mixed case). It is assumed that a house can either have a cat or a dog.

I tried writing the code, but it does not look good and would appreciate your help on refactoring or improving the design.

```
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndCatExist = false;
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndDogExist = false;
    List<House>[] arrOfHouseList = getArrOfHouseList();
    for(List<House> houseList : arrOfHouseList){
       Boolean isHousesWithCat = true;
       Boolean isHousesWithDog = true;
       for(House house: houseList){
          if(house.hasCat()){
             isHousesWithDog = false;
          }else{
             isHousesWithCat = false;
          }
       }
       if(!isHousesWithDog && ! isHousesWithCat){
          return false; //This is mixed case. The list contains both of kind of houses
       }
       isListWithHouseAndCatExist=isHousesWithCat?true:isListWithHouseAndCatExist;
       isListWithHouseAndDogExist=isHousesWithDog?true:isListWithHouseAndDogExist;  
    }

    // Now to check that we have atleast one list with all House-Cat and atleast one list with all
    // House-Dog
    if(!isListWithHouseAndCatExist || !isListWithHouseAndDogExist){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
```

As you can see I had to use four Boolean variable to validate conditions. Could you please help to improve the code.

Comment: Do you want to make sure looping only once through each list of houses?  And are you able to use streams?

Comment: @wjans The four Boolean variables looks too much for the work. I was thinking if I could do it neatly using only two Boolean variables or do you think this is good enough code.

Comment: On the side, I think this question will be well suited for the "Code Review" site of "Stack Exchange". https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use streams and only want to iterate once, you could do something like this:

```
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndCatExist = false;
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndDogExist = false;
    List<House>[] arrOfHouseList = getArrOfHouseList();
    for(List<House> houseList : arrOfHouseList){

        Set<Boolean> hasCatFlags = new HashSet<>();
        for(House house: houseList){
            hasCatFlags.add(house.hasCat());
        }
        if(hasCatFlags.size() > 1){
            return false; //This is mixed case. The list contains both of kind of houses
        }
        if (hasCatFlags.contains(true)) {
            isListWithHouseAndCatExist = true;
        } else if (hasCatFlags.contains(false)) {
            isListWithHouseAndDogExist = true;
        }
    }

    return isListWithHouseAndCatExist && isListWithHouseAndDogExist;
```

If you can use streams but want to iterate only once, you could do something like this:

```
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndCatExist = false;
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndDogExist = false;
    List<House>[] arrOfHouseList = getArrOfHouseList();
    for(List<House> houseList : arrOfHouseList){

        Set<Boolean> hasCatFlags = houseList.stream().map(House::hasCat).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if(hasCatFlags.size() > 1){
            return false; //This is mixed case. The list contains both of kind of houses
        }

        if (hasCatFlags.contains(true)) {
            isListWithHouseAndCatExist = true;
        } else if (hasCatFlags.contains(false)) {
            isListWithHouseAndDogExist = true;
        }
    }

    return isListWithHouseAndCatExist && isListWithHouseAndDogExist;
```

And if you can use streams and don't mind iterating twice, you could do this:

```
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndCatExist = false;
    Boolean isListWithHouseAndDogExist = false;
    for(List<House> houseList : getArrOfHouseList()){
        if (houseList.stream().allMatch(House::hasCat)) {
            isListWithHouseAndCatExist = true;
        } else if (houseList.stream().noneMatch(House::hasCat)) {
            isListWithHouseAndDogExist = true;
        } else {
            return false;//mixed case
        } 
    }

    return isListWithHouseAndCatExist && isListWithHouseAndDogExist;
```

Comment: Nice answer, Thank you.